# Computing hitting times from the stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

My question is whether it is possible to compute hitting times from the previously calculated stationary distribution $\pi$ of a continuous-time Markov process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.  I know that, from learning about Markov chains in discrete time, $$\pi(j) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}_j(T_j)} \,\,\, \forall j\,$$
(such that $T_j$ is the return time to state $j$). But, is there any way to compute $\mathbb{E}_i(T_j)$ for $i \neq j$ from $\pi$ in the discrete time case? Or, more generally, in the continuous time case, if we have some subset $A \subset \mathbb{S}$ of a (finite) state space, then is there a way to compute $\mathbb{E}_i(T_A)$ directly from (or at least using) the stationary distribution $\pi$, where $T_A = \inf\{t:X_t \in A\}$ and $i \notin A$ ?

Let me give my specific example to focus on in order to further clarify. Consider a Markov process with state space (ordered) $\mathbb{S}=\{0,1,2,12\}$ and a generator matrix (with rows and columns in the same order)

$$Q =\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & 4 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -4 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & -6 
\end{pmatrix} \,.$$

Computing the stationary distribution, we obtain $\pi = (\pi_0, \pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_{12}) = (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{9})$.  Now, we can set $g(i) = \mathbb{E}_i(T_0)$ for $i \neq 0$, $g(0) = 0$, and solve the following system of three equations $(i \neq 0 \implies i = 1,2,12)$ for $g(i)$:
$$\sum_{j \in \mathbb{S}} Q(i,j)g(j) = -1\,.$$

Doing this, we obtain $g = (g(0),g(1),g(2),g(12)) = (0,1,\frac{3}{4},1)$.  My question is if, for instance, we could compute $g(12)$ directly from the stationary distribution $\pi$.

Comment: The notation $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ suggests that the process in question is continuous-time, but the rest of the question suggests that instead we are considering a discrete-time Markov chain. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Math1000 hopefully my edit helps to clarify.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Of course $\pi$ alone cannot determine every $E_i(T_j)$. Consider for example the simple random walks on a discrete circle and on the complete graph of the same size, then $\pi$ is the same for these two graphs (i.e. uniform) but the mean hitting times $E_i(T_j)$ are quite different.

Comment: Minor remark: a hitting time such as $T_A$ is always defined as an infimum, not a minimum, if only to account for the event where the random walk never hits $A$ (recall that $\inf\varnothing=+\infty$ and that $\min\varnothing$ does not exist).

Comment: @Did duly noted

Comment: Re the edit, note that I provided two transition matrices on the same state space with the same stationary distribution which yield two different $g$s (in the notation of your edit). Ergo?